# Show value of particular column as Header in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, pivot

I am creating a web app in which I have a requirement where I want to display a column value as a header

Example

```
SELECT Name, Leave
FROM tblUser 
INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID = tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
```

From that query, I get these results:

```
Name     Leave
---------------
Test1       5
Test2      10
test3       2
```

Now I want to get these values as

```
Test1 Test2 Test3
-----------------
  5     10    2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using pivot

```
select pv.* from
(SELECT Name,Leave
FROM tblUser INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
)X
pivot
(max(leave) for name in ([Test1],[Test2],[Test3])) as pv
```

For Dynamic PIVOT

```
declare @sql varchar(max)='',@col_list varchar(8000)=''

set @col_list = (select distinct quotename([Name])+',' from (SELECT Name,Leave
    FROM tblUser INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
    )X
for xml path(''))

set @col_list = left (@col_list,len(@col_list)-1)

set @sql = 'select '+@col_list+' from
    (SELECT Name,Leave
    FROM tblUser INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
    )X
pivot (max([Leave]) for [Name] in ('+@col_list+'))pv'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: I am getting this error

Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#table'.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use condition aggregate function. `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` or `MIN`

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Test1' THEN Leave END) Test1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Test2' THEN Leave END) Test2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Test3' THEN Leave END) Test3
FROM tblUser 
INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
```

**EDIT**

If your column  want to create dynamic you can try to use *Dynamic PIVOT*

create your SQL statement and make condition aggregate function by connect SQL string. then use execute it Dynamically.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', MAX(CASE WHEN Name = ''' + Name+''' THEN Leave END) ' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
            FROM tblUser 
            INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET  @query= 'SELECT '+ @cols+'
FROM tblUser 
INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID'

execute(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d7da11f6f7a62985882f2aa50d28204a)

Comment: Test1, Test2, Test3 is dynamic

Comment: it is MSSQL sir.

Answer (score 2):

try by using case when

```
select max( case when name='Test1' then Leave end) as test1,
max( case when name='Test2' then Leave end) as test2,
max( case when name='Test3' then Leave end) as test3 from 
tblUser INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster
ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find your result from the query as shown below. Here I have taken your query output in a temporary table.

```
Create table #finalData(ColName Varchar(30), Leave INT)
INSERT INTO #finalData Values('Test1', 5),('Test2', 10),('Test3', 2)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);  

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.ColName)   
            FROM #finalData c  
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   
        ,1,1,'')  

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from   
            (  
                select ColName  
                    , Leave  
                from #finalData  
           ) x  
            pivot   
            (  
                 max(Leave)  
                for ColName in (' + @cols + ')  
            ) p '  

execute(@query)  
DROP TABLE #finalData
```

Hope this will help you.
The output is as shown below

```
Test1   Test2   Test3
5       10      2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select pv.* from
(SELECT Name,Leave
FROM tblUser INNER JOIN tblLeaveMaster ON tblUser.EmployeeID=tblLeaveMaster.EmployeeID
)X
pivot
(max(leave) for name in ([Test1],[Test2],[Test3])) as pv
```

Note:- this work for me but how to use where condition base on dropdown list selected value.
eg: if wants to show only 2020 and not 2019.